# Laravel combine two tables posts + tags

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables one for links and second one for tags.

When user create new tag it will write to tags table new row. 
Now what I want to do is to get all user links with tags. I have done this:

```
$data['links'] = User::find($user->id)->links()->get();
  foreach ($data['links'] as $key => $value) {
    $data['links'][$key]['tags'] = DB::table('tags')
                                ->where('user_id', $user->id)
                                ->where('link_id', $value->id)
                                ->get();
  }
```

It's working, but I think that there is better way to do that than this.

Comment: You should look into relationships.  You'd need to setup a pivot table called tags_links since it sounds like a many to many relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user model

```
public function links()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Link');
}
```

link model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

public function tags()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Tag');
}
```

tag model

```
public function link()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Link');
}
```

So we are ready to go..

```
User::with('links.tags')->get()
```

Comment: Yeah , use Eloquent ORM is better .